# Win 8.1 BSOD when booted without main monitor

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, bsod

I'm on Lenovo Y580 laptop with win 8.1. At home, I connect the laptop via VGA cable to a computer monitor, set it as the main display and set to display only on the computer monitor, effectively my laptop screen goes black and I lower down the lid for convenience (not all the way down as it goes to sleep and I want it to work that way). All works like a charm. When I unplug the computer monitor, the display automatically switches to laptop screen and I can work normally. When I unplug the computer monitor, turn off my laptop and turn it on again then everything works. When I turn off the laptop first, then unplug the monitor and turn on the laptop again I get BSOD on startup, windows launches only in safe mode. I suspect that this is probably a bug in the display driver or something. The BSOD message says **system_service_exception** and gets stuck at 0% collecting information...

How can I fix this? I am currently running safe mode with networking. I am traveling a lot and I don't have any monitor to connect to my laptop at this moment.

Comment: Please add details about that BSOD. All the numbers and filenames, when present.

Comment: Added what I could gather ATM. I could investigate additional memory dumps or something if that's necessary

Comment: Bug Check 0x3B: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION is often casued by GPU drivers. Updaet the driver

Comment: I updated gpu drivers and installed all avaible windows updates. Still occurs.

Comment: share the dmp files, maybe I can see more.

Comment: I was unable to gather full kernel dump, something else wasn't working properly. Fortunately I installed windows 10 and the problem disappeared. Thanks for your help.